# Permut matrix and create news in R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, permutation

I have a distance matix:

```
    A               B          C            D           E          F        G
A                           
B   0.6                     
C   0.38461538     0.42857143                   
D   0.25           0.5333      0.30769231               
E   0.36363636     0.41666667  0.41666667   0.27272727          
F   0.53846154     0.57142857  0.57142857   0.33333333  0.3     
G   0.45454545     0.5         0.5          0.36363636  0.125 0.22222222
```

Then, I want to permut this matrix in new matrix combinations of 4 x 4 where the order is not important, for example ABCD is equal to DCBA.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would follow these steps:

**1)** Convert distance table into numeric matrix `M <- as.matrix(dist)`

**2)** Define the combinations of four elements between your 10 rows `sam <- combn(1:10, 4)`. This is going to result on a matrix with 4 rows and as many columns as the combinations of 10 elements over 4 (210 in this case).

**3)** All the matrices you are interested on are `M[sam[,i],sam[,i]]` for `i in 1:210`